# How do I configure TFS to work with various merge tools

Tags: tfs, merge, winmerge, beyondcompare

Originally the question was "How do I configure WinMerge as the compare and merge tool for TFS". However, I am changing it because [TehOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21932/tehone) answered this more general form of the question.

I would have though this would have been asked already on Stackoverflow. I found the answer elsewhere, but I am asking/answering here. It's now a community wiki.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When I was looking for how to do this, I found this post to be invaluable:
http://blogs.msdn.com/jmanning/articles/535573.aspx

Comment: Your answer made me change the question and make it a community wiki.

Comment: Glad I could be of help, but the real credit of course goes to James Manning for that blog post of his. It really helped me out. I can't stand the built in tools of VSS/TFS. So, being able to use my already installed Beyond Compare is great.

Thanks for making this a wiki for everyone to refer back to later.

Comment: The parameters he uses for SourceGear DiffMerge are incorrect.  The correct parameters can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17523972/7850)

Answer (score 12):

The long procedure is provided in [a Rory Primrose blog posting](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2007/06/19/using-winmerge-with-tfs.aspx)

The short answer is the argument list for compare is:

```
/x /e /ub /wl /dl %6 /dr %7 %1 %2
```

and the argument list for merge is:

```
/x /e /ub /wl /dl %6 /dr %7 %1 %2 %4
```

Sometimes Winmerge does not return 0 and  TFS will think the merge was canceled. You need to use the following wrapper batch file for merging:

```
@rem winmergeFromTFS.bat
@rem 2007-08-01
@rem File created by Paul Oliver to get Winmerge to play nicely with TFS
@rem
@rem To use, tell TFS to use this command as the merge command
@rem And then set this as your arguments:
@rem  %6 %7 %1 %2 %4
"C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMerge.exe" /x /e /ub /wl /dl %1 /dr %2 %3 %4 %5
exit 0
```

And then you set the argument list to:

```
%6 %7 %1 %2 %
```

exit 0

Comment: I think a typo, but the argument list should be %6 %7 %1 %2 %4

Answer (score 0):

For SourceGear DiffMerge, you need to change the default command line to:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\SourceGear\Vault Client\sgdm.exe

I found the parameters in [this thread](http://support.sourcegear.com/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=8514) on the SourceGear support forums, as well as on James Manning's blog mentioned by @TehOne, but **the arguments given there are incorrect** and result in the auto-merge being executed in reverse, i.e. old code overwrites new code.  The correct arguments are:

> /m /t1=%6 /t2=%7 /t3=%8 /c=%9 %1 %3 %2 /r=%4