# How do you change the program team explorer uses for comparisons?

Tags: tfs, version-control, team-explorer, difftool

I would like to have team explorer use BeyondCompare or SourceGear's diffmerge in order to do my conflict resolution in team explorer. I know its possible, but where is the setting for that and what is the syntax for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks like it would answer your question
[How do I configure TFS to work with various merge tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313908/how-do-i-configure-tfs-to-work-with-various-merge-tools)