# GVim as merge tool for TFS

Tags: vim, merge

I want to use GVim as a merge tool for TFS 2010.
I can't figure out the Arguments for GVim.
Specifically the argument %4, when I use it I get an empty buffer for it. if I don't use it I get an error message that I must use it.

[image]

Comment: Not strictly an answer but have you seen http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3808

Comment: @Benj, Yes, seen it. that is for working in vim and using the tfs source control. What I want is that when I am working in VS2010 and I click the button to "Merge Changes In Merge Tool" - GVim will open as that tool.

Comment: Yeh, I know, it was just a shameless plug ;-)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313908/how-do-i-configure-tfs-to-work-with-various-merge-tools), and the [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmanning/archive/2006/02/20/diff-merge-configuration-in-team-foundation-common-command-and-argument-values.aspx) in the accepted answer may help.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that vim uses diff while it should use something like diff3 for merge...

Comment: also I encountered another gvim diff issue that while comparing a file against server latest version; in gvim I don't see the changes although other diff tools like the VS default comparing tool and also tortoise diff tool does actually shows the changes...  I really like vim bug I think that for comparing and merging something else should be used...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be exactly to your liking, but here's how I use GVim for a merge tool.

I set it up to do a two-way merge: it has the 'source' on the left (where I'm merging *from*), and the merge file on the right (starts off as what my destination branch has for information).

I set it up like this:

```
command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\gvim.exe
argument: -c "vert diffsplit %1 " %4 -c "wincmd l|0read %2  |diff"
```

What this does is as follows:

- Reads in the 'source' file on the left, and splits the window (-c "vert diffsplit %1")
- Opens up on the right side the merge result (%4)
- Runs a quick script which:

  - Moves over the right window (wincmd l)
  - Reads in my existing changes in the branch (0read %2)
  - Re-runs the diff algorithm (diff)

This lets me "diff" my work against the incoming merge, and saving the right hand side will resolve the merge.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot suggests you are using Vim 7.3 . According to Vim site:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Running_diff

> At some point, the MyDiff function provided by the "Vim without Cream"
>   installer has been modified. As of Vim 7.3.138 it is still broken.

However, You can try the following verbose-mode parameters

```
command : gvim
argument: -V -od %1 %2
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't have issues with diff. maybe because I did not use the "Vim without Cream" (sourceforge) but rather the gvim from vim.org.

Comment: then just try arguments :
-d %1 %2 %4

Comment: Still the %4 argument produce an empty window.

Comment: From command line you do "gvimdiff -O branch1.txt base.txt branch2.txt merge.txt", this means that TFS merge tool should name these files in that order: %2 %1 %4 %3 , maybe you can try it in that order?

Comment: I tried, still TFS does not provide a file for %4, thus it does not work.