# VS2010 uses WinMerge but TFS2010's Pending Changes tab uses DiffMerge

Tags: visual-studio-2010, configuration

from VS2010, if I select compare from the context menu, WinMerge is used, but when doing a merge with TFS2010 tools in VS (Pending Changes tab), it insists on using the defautl diffmerge tool that sucks.

Where do I configure TFS to use my own diff/merge tool?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I configure TFS to work with various merge tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313908/how-do-i-configure-tfs-to-work-with-various-merge-tools)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://blog.paulbouwer.com/2010/01/31/replace-diffmerge-tool-in-visual-studio-team-system-with-winmerge/

Configure Visual Studio

**Open Source Control > Visual Studio Team Foundation under the Tools > Options menu in Visual Studio.

Click on Configure User Tools …** and the Configure User Tools dialog will become available.

Do not forget to restart Visual studio to load configuration.

Comment: Ahh! I only had a configuration for compare and not merge. thanks

Comment: the blog post in this answer has clear steps with nice screenshots but if you just want to import a reg file see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19872167/224976)

Answer (score 2):

[Download the reg file](http://www.neovolve.com/2007/06/19/using-winmerge-with-tfs/), import into regedit.exe and you're done! Or if you want to do it manually in Visual Studio do the following:

```
Click on Tools menu
Click on Options menu item
Expand Source Control tree item
Select Visual Studio Team Foundation Server tree item
Click on Configure User Tools... button
```

Comparing

To use WinMerge as the Compare/Diff tool:

```
Click the Add... button
For Extension, type *
For Operation, select Compare
For Command, browse for C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMerge.exe
For Arguments, type /x /e /ub /wl /dl %6 /dr %7 %1 %2
Click OK to accept
```

Merging

To use WinMerge as the Merge tool:

```
Click the Add... button
For Extension, type *
For Operation, select Merge
For Command, browse for C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMerge.exe
For Arguments, type /x /e /ub /wl /dl %6 /dr %7 %1 %2 %4
Click OK to accept
```

Note: You need to click on the Save button on the tool bar within WinMerge merge to commit a merge before exiting the screen